# Creating table for union query - syntax error

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I need to create a table from the union of two queries.

This query works exactly as I need it to:

```
SELECT portligh_lotteryTest.scores.team FROM portligh_lotteryTest.scores ORDER BY portligh_lotteryTest.scores.count DESC LIMIT 5 
union 
SELECT portligh_lotteryTest.scores.team FROM portligh_lotteryTest.scores ORDER BY portligh_lotteryTest.scores.count ASC LIMIT 3
```

Once I add the create statement I begin to get errors

```
 CREATE TABLE portligh_lotteryTest.cTop8 (team int) AS 
(SELECT portligh_lotteryTest.scores.team FROM portligh_lotteryTest.scores ORDER BY portligh_lotteryTest.scores.count DESC LIMIT 5)
 union 
(SELECT portligh_lotteryTest.scores.team FROM portligh_lotteryTest.scores ORDER BY portligh_lotteryTest.scores.count ASC LIMIT 3)
```

The error is:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT portligh_lotteryTest.scores.team FROM portligh_lotteryTest.scores ORDER ' at line 1

Comment: Why do you have parentheses around the select statement? No need for them.

Comment: `uniol` is this typo?

Comment: Both of the above are correct. Shadow I removed the outside set of parens - then got the error stop at uniol

Comment: CREATE TABLE portligh_lotteryTest.cTop8 (team int)AS(SELECT portligh_lotteryTest.scores.team FROM portligh_lotteryTest.scores ORDER BY portligh_lotteryTest.scores.count DESC LIMIT 5) union all (SELECT portligh_lotteryTest.scores.team FROM portligh_lotteryTest.scores ORDER BY portligh_lotteryTest.scores.count ASC LIMIT 3)

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query:-

```
CREATE TABLE portligh_lotteryTest.cTop8 (team int) AS 
(SELECT portligh_lotteryTest.scores.team FROM portligh_lotteryTest.scores ORDER BY portligh_lotteryTest.scores.count DESC LIMIT 5
 union all
 SELECT portligh_lotteryTest.scores.team FROM portligh_lotteryTest.scores ORDER BY portligh_lotteryTest.scores.count ASC LIMIT 3)
```